# Simple Powershell script stopped working, looking for assistance

Tags: transactions, signature

I will start by saying I am not a programmer, I have been dabbling with chatgpt for a while and I am hoping someone could help me understand why my script no longer works. I use a script to pull some SPL transfer amounts from signatures. I have a simple version made to pull just 1 to test that everything is working then I use a longer script that pulls all the data I'm looking for. Both scripts worked great until this weeks attempt. The only thing I can see on solscan that has changed is the transaction version changed from legacy to 0. Here is my script below.

```
# Define RPC URL and headers, including the API key
$rpcUrl = "https://mainnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key=YOUR KEY"
$headers = @{
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}

# Transaction signature to analyze
$transactionSignature = "5ufVkfo6YFd7B7PM8dCEu472dwfnYajd7NsT3WBP35zrnWtgXikLYFcfuPADxrhwUEgvWEAhxQ8SsTPUjqybQwSF"

# Prepare the body for the RPC call to get transaction details
$body = @{
    jsonrpc = "2.0"
    id      = 1
    method  = "getTransaction"
    params  = @($transactionSignature, "jsonParsed")
} | ConvertTo-Json

# Fetch transaction details
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $rpcUrl -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $body

# Define the decimal factor for RNDR (8 decimal places, adjusted based on feedback)
$decimalFactor = 1e8

# Let's iterate through the instructions and find token transfer operations
foreach ($instruction in $response.result.transaction.message.instructions) {
    if ($instruction.programId -eq "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA" -and 
        ($instruction.parsed.type -eq "transfer" -or $instruction.parsed.type -eq "transferChecked")) {
        $info = $instruction.parsed.info
        $destination = $info.destination
        # Adjust amount for decimal places
        $amount = [math]::Round($info.tokenAmount.amount / $decimalFactor, 2) # Adjusted rounding for 2 decimal places
        Write-Host "Found transfer to ${destination}: $amount RNDR"
    }
}
```

If I use the signature in the code above, it does not work. Nothing is returned. If I use a signature from last week, or any prior it works just fine, so something has changed. For example this signature will produce the 4 SPL transfers that were apart of this signature.
4zpGoMnBmixqKj9pHDUNdrfpXDcXy9QkWW5Usxk8rMdPdZxJ9xQTHF273R6xwJkc8Fv94UiV9bQ7TxsSXDs8R8Ri
this is from last week. Any help would be appreciated!
thank you.